# Angular js sort data by filter options

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have filter function which is currently only return name values in my table, I want also add **ascending** and **descending** options to this filter.

**What I've done so far**

1. I can get values of all my inputs including `name` and `asc/desc` request
2. I can return results based on `name` input

**What I need**

1. Add `asc / desc` request to returned results

#### Code

`HTML`

```
<form [formGroup]="filterForm" (ngSubmit)="search(column.real_name)">
  <div class="card search-box p-2">
    <div class="mb-2">
      <label for="">Search By {{ column.name }}</label> <br>
      <input nz-input formControlName="formInput" placeholder="Type here..." />
    </div>

    <div class="mb-2">
      <label for="sort">Sort Order</label> <br>
      <nz-select ngModel="none" formControlName="formSort" class="text-left mr-2" style="width:100%;">
          <nz-option nzValue="none" nzLabel="None"></nz-option>
          <nz-option nzValue="asc" nzLabel="Ascending"></nz-option>
          <nz-option nzValue="desc" nzLabel="Descending"></nz-option>
      </nz-select>
    </div>

    <div class="mb-2">
      <label for="op">Filter Column</label> <br>
      <nz-select ngModel="contains" formControlName="formColumn" class="text-left mr-2" style="width:100%;">
          <nz-option nzValue="contains" nzLabel="Contains"></nz-option>
          <nz-option nzValue="like" nzLabel="Like"></nz-option>
      </nz-select>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning w-100 mt-2"><i class="fe fe-search"></i> Search</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

`Script` (commented)

```
filterForm: FormGroup


constructor(
  public formBuilder: FormBuilder,
) {
   this.filterForm =  this.formBuilder.group({
     formInput:  [null, Validators.required],
     formSort:  [null, Validators.required],
     formColumn:  [null, Validators.required],
   })
}


search(column): void {
  const filterFormData = this.filterForm.value;

  // values
  console.log('formInput: ', filterFormData.formInput); // Already implemented (name input)
  console.log('formSort: ', filterFormData.formSort); // Now I want to implement this value
  console.log('formColumn: ', filterFormData.formColumn);
  console.log('formColumnName: ', column);

  this.visible = false;

  // return results in table (currently only name input is presented)
  this.listOfData = this.listOfData.filter((item: DataItem) =>
    item[column].toLowerCase().indexOf(filterFormData.formInput.toLowerCase()) !== -1
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create a compare function and pass that to the native sort function (add after your filter function):

```
search(column): void {
  const filterFormData = this.filterForm.value;

  // values
  console.log('formInput: ', filterFormData.formInput); // Already implemented (name input)
  console.log('formSort: ', filterFormData.formSort); // Now I want to implement this value
  console.log('formColumn: ', filterFormData.formColumn);
  console.log('formColumnName: ', column);

  this.visible = false;

  // return results in table (currently only name input is presented)
  this.listOfData = this.listOfData.filter((item: DataItem) =>
    item[column].toLowerCase().indexOf(filterFormData.formInput.toLowerCase()) !== -1
  );
  if (filterFormData.formSort === "asc") {
    const sortAsc = (a,b) => a[column] < b[column] ? -1 : a[column] > b[column] ? 1 : 0;
    this.listOfData.sort(sortAsc);
  } else if filterFormData.formSort === "desc"{
    const sortDesc = (a,b) => a[column] < b[column] ? 1 : a[column] > b[column] ? -1 : 0;
    this.listOfData.sort(sortDesc);
  }
}
```

Comment: hi, doesn't seem to do anything, would you mind place your code into my function? probably I've placed your code in wrong place!

Comment: @mafortis, see my edit, make sure I was correct with the values of filterFormData.formSort === "asc" and that it actually steps into one of the if statements